# If I change a Connected App's OAuth Scopes, do users need to re-authorize so that the connected app now has those Scopes available?

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps, authorization

I have created a Connected App in "Org A" which users are self-authorizing in another org, "Org B". If I add a new OAuth scope to the Connected App in "Org A", will the self-authorizations in "Org B" be revoked automatically? Or will the OAuth connection still work in "Org B", but only with the old scopes that were set in "Org A" (before adding the new scope)?

I understand that if the user re-authorizes *after* the scope change has been done in "Org A", then that OAuth connection will include the new scopes as well, right?

Thanks very much!

Comment: The authorization is based on the issued access token with whatever scopes were configured at the time. While this token is valid, client in org B will continue to work.

Comment: @identigral This should be an answer, not a comment.